# Power Supply And Power Cable at Equinix Palo Alto?

Tags: cable, power-supply-unit

I will be doing a server installation at the Palo Alto Equinix Data Center soon and I'm coming in from overseas so I wondering if any of you can help me out regarding power supply can power cable issues.

My server power supply is

INPUT
100-240V AC ~50/60Hz
MAX AC CURRENT 10A-5A

Do I need a DC power supply?

and the power cable plug head I'm currently using is BS 1363 plug head. What kind of head do I need?

Comment: Draft was not saved after I logged in. Please don't just -1

Comment: That is a question you **have** to ask the DC people, not some semi-random internet site.

Comment: I asked them, but since I'm just the vendor providing a service for my client the datacenter will not release the information to me. C'mon guys, I'm sure there is definitely someone who has such experience. Isn't the point of such a site to have a place to ask questions and help the community? I wouldn't have posted the question here if I got the answer from the datacenter right?

Comment: @d123 Dude, I answered your question.

Comment: @ewwhite Yeah man. Thank you very very much!! Waiting to be able to accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need either a simple [NEMA C13/C14 cable](http://www.automation-drive.com/EX/05-15-01/c-14%2520to%2520c-13%2520V.jpg) if you're using 208V power at Equinix...

If using 115V power at Equinix, you will need a [C13-NEMA 5-15 cable](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/buynowall_assets/product_images/3993164.jpg).

The data center should have both available to you. Seriously... they will have a pile of cables.

Comment: Hey ewwhite, Thank you very much for your reply as compared to some others who aren't very helpful. So I guess since my power supply is 100-240V it is supported, only thing is to ensure that the power cable is correct. Also does my power supply being AC matter? Or do I need DC current power supply?

Comment: AC power supply is correct. The range listed on the power supply means it can operate within that voltage range. The only difference will be the cable. Cables are available at the facility.